# How to remove border and scrollbars of TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can I remove border and scroll bars of a TWebBrowser component?
i searched a lot and all answers were about same:

http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/torry/printcode.php?id=1171

http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=18

but does not work (it do nothing!). in my case i want to view a local file in browser.

how can i hide border and scroll bars?

Comment: "but does not work" - How doesn't it work? Does it do nothing? Does it give you an error? Does it do something other than what you intended?

Comment: Your mistake is probably that you're attempting to do this on app startup, form show, or similar. You need to do this after each document finishes loading, using the `OnDocumentComplete` event. Attempting to do this before a document has finished loading will result in an Access Violation, which you don't speak of, but I'm assuming that's what you mean by "but does not work".

Comment: it do nothing.... i placed the code in NavigateCompleted2

Comment: It worked fine for me in `OnDocumentComplete`. By the way, by default I don't even have borders in the first place.

Comment: i cant understand why but the result is different in different pages... when you navigate (via TWebBrowser) to Google.com you have no border and no scrollbars by default, when you search something in Google, scrollbars will appear because of page height change and you can hide them with the code in the link above (2nd link), but when you navigate to Yahoo.com there will be border (but there is no border when you navigate with Google Chrome) and there is scrollbars too and you cant hide them with the code... what changes in these pages?

Comment: Maybe because certain webpages have borders on different levels? Take a look at how that code works. It assumes one particular HTML element will have scrollbars, but different websites might utilize scrollbars in a different element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css, the TWebbrowser uses internet explorer (an horror engine for webmaster -> overflow:hidden ). This style workaround works well for me (not in body node but in html  ), in your local file try to add this style:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
html
{
 position:fixed;
 overflow:hidden;
 -ms-overflow-style: none;
    border:0px;
 }</style>
 </head>
<body>
 Test
</body>
</html>
```

In my case it works (delphi xe 4 and windows 7), I made a webview with a small size without scrollbars.